# Zend Framework getting started with Eclipse

Tags: php, zend-framework

Where can I find a good tutorial to get started with the latest version of Zend Framework using Eclipse or Netbeans? I would like Eclipse as my IDE as I like these features:

```
* Syntax highlighting
* Outline
* Code assist
* Code templates
```

Besides that I use Mysql 5 as the db.

Is there any free / paid video tutorials for the Zend framework as well ?

Comment: there is website for ZF : http://www.zendcasts.com/

Answer (score 2):

There a quite a few videos on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=zend+framework&search_type=&aq=6&oq=zend) that show how to use ZF and MVC.  I would check out [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJ7UYyoLK48) video which shows how to use Zend Studio.  Zend Studio isn't free, but you can download a free 30 day trial version.

Other than that, you can install and try the [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) plugin and check out the [tutorials](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/TUTORIALS) for using it.  PDT is a free opensource product, and you can use it with the ZF.bat/ZF.sh tool to build your ZF apps.

Comment: is there a tutorial like here: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ which shows a walk through of the PDT plugin with ZF.bat/ZF.sh tool

Comment: ZEND Studio contains an integrated ZF.bat/ZF.sh tool.  If you aren't using ZEND Studio, then you will have to use ZF.bat/ZF.sh from the command line.

I haven't seen a video that compbines the PDT plugin with the ZF.bat/ZF.sh tool, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to "QuickStart" of Zend. It is a good start point. Link is http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart It explains step by step where you can start and how you can build your structure. And i will recommend you two books.

1-) Beginning Zend Framework ([http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Zend-Framework-Armando-Padilla/dp/1430218258/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1258554221&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218258))

2-) Pro Zend Framework Techniques: Build a Full CMS Project ([http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Zend-Framework-Techniques-Project/dp/1430218797/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1258554221&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218797))

I could not find vidoes about Zend Framework. Those books and Quickstart of Zend helped me to understand of framework.

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to explore these [ZF tutorials](http://www.killerphp.com/zend-framework/). They were very helpful along with Rob Allen's tutorials on his Akrabat blog.

Hope that helps.